# Angular Material Library Form Controls Not Styling Correctly

Tags: css, forms, angular, input, styling

I've been running into an issue with the form controls in the Angular2 Library. It's not a problem with any of my own SCSS as the problem still appears when it's commented out. Basically, I want the buttons to look and behave in the same way they do when demoed in the Angular Library, but instead they're sort of 'doubling up' with some styling from the Angular code while still displaying other checkboxes or radio buttons inside or next to them (I added some screenshots since it's a bit hard to describe.)

[image]

[image]

I've gotten them to work in this project before, I think somewhere along the line a stylesheet or ts file may have gotten lost. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example, [here's how](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: as already said, you need to provide more information about what you're doing. That's probably loading library error...have looked at you console on dev tools to see if it shows any error?

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with the extension of my styles.scss file somewhere along the line it got changed from an 'scss' file to just a 'css' file. Changing the file to an scss file fixed all my issues.